# Display data with pagination

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

**UPDATE:**
Using @kyeiti's solution, I managed to get the other info where I need it, but I'm unable to navigate; I can go back and forward on the left side, but I can't get the right side to update. Also, if this could be accomplished with a single external PHP file it would be great. To make things clear, I put the whole thing online, you can check it out [here](http://www.rujzgalvanic.tk/playground). Also, I updated the code sections to reflect the latest changes.

**UPDATE 2:**

After some more help from @kyeiti, I'm trying to get it working with only 1 external PHP. The JS code is exactly as per @kyeiti's updated answer, while my art.php (now the only external file) looks like below. When I open index.php, I get nothing related to the two divs in the code. I also tried inserting them into the index file itself, but obviously that didn't work either...

Current art.php:

```
<?php


$username = "root"; //mysql username
$password = ""; //mysql password
$hostname = "localhost"; //hostname
$databasename = '2199'; //databasename

//get pic id from ajax request
if(isset($_POST["pic"]) && is_numeric($_POST["pic"]))
{
    $current_picture = filter_var($_POST["pic"], FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
}else{
    $current_picture=1;
}

//Connect to Database
$mysqli = new mysqli($hostname, $username, $password, $databasename);

if ($mysqli->connect_error){   
    die('Error : ('. $mysqli->connect_errno .') '. $mysqli->connect_error);
}

//get next picture id
$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT id FROM gola WHERE id > $current_picture ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 1")->fetch_object();
if($result){
    $next_id = $result->id;
}

//get previous picture id
$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT id FROM gola WHERE id < $current_picture ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1")->fetch_object();
if($result){
    $prev_id = $result->id;
}

//get details of current from database
$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT artikel, slika1 FROM gola WHERE id = $current_picture LIMIT 1")->fetch_object();

if($result){

    //construct next/previous button
    $prev_button = (isset($prev_id) && $prev_id>0)?'<a href="#" data-id="'.$prev_id.'" class="get_pic"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-circle-arrow-left rujz"></span></a>':'';
    $next_button = (isset($next_id) && $next_id>0)?'<a href="#" data-id="'.$next_id.'" class="get_pic"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-circle-arrow-right rujz"></span></a>':'';

    //output html

echo "<div id='loaded_picture'>";
echo "test"; // Put everything that goes into the picture div here
echo "</div>";

echo "<div id='loaded_text'>";
echo "test"; // And everything that goes into the text div here
echo "</div>";

}
```

**Original post:**

I have two main divs in my page, the left side displays a photo and the right side should display some info about a specific product.

I get all the data out of MySQL and managed to hack together a working solution to navigate. I can go forward and backward using next/prev buttons and the image changes.

Now for some code:

HTML (index.php):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="layout.css">
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Syncopate' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
     $.post( "art.php", { pic: "1"}, function( data ) {
           $("#picture").html( data );
     });
     $.post( "info.php", { id: "1"}, function( data ) {
           $("#info").html( data );
     });

     $("#picture").on("click",".get_pic", function(e){
           var picture_id = $(this).attr('data-id');
           $("#picture").html("<div style=\"margin:50px auto;width:50px;\"><img src=\"loader.gif\" /></div>");
           $.post( "art.php", { pic: picture_id}, function( data ) {
                 $("#picture").html( data );
           });
           return false;
     });

          $("#info").on("click",".get_info", function(e){
           var info_id = $(this).attr('data-id');
           $("#info").html("<div style=\"margin:50px auto;width:50px;\"><img src=\"loader.gif\" /></div>");
           $.post( "info.php", { pic: info_id}, function( data ) {
                 $("#info").html( data );
           });
           return false;
     });
});
</script>
<title>2199</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="navbar-wrapper">
  <div class="container"> <img src="logo.png" class="boxy"> </div>
</div>
<div class="jumbotron special">
  <div id="picture" align="center"> </div>
</div>
<div class="jumbotron special2">
  <div id="info" align="center"> </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

HTML (art.php):

```
$username = "root"; //mysql username
$password = ""; //mysql password
$hostname = "localhost"; //hostname
$databasename = '2199'; //databasename

//get pic id from ajax request
if(isset($_POST["pic"]) && is_numeric($_POST["pic"]))
{
    $current_picture = filter_var($_POST["pic"], FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
}else{
    $current_picture=1;
}

//Connect to Database
$mysqli = new mysqli($hostname, $username, $password, $databasename);

if ($mysqli->connect_error){   
    die('Error : ('. $mysqli->connect_errno .') '. $mysqli->connect_error);
}

//get next picture id
$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT id FROM gola WHERE id > $current_picture ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 1")->fetch_object();
if($result){
    $next_id = $result->id;
}

//get previous picture id
$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT id FROM gola WHERE id < $current_picture ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1")->fetch_object();
if($result){
    $prev_id = $result->id;
}

//get details of current from database
$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT artikel, slika1 FROM gola WHERE id = $current_picture LIMIT 1")->fetch_object();

if($result){

    //construct next/previous button
    $prev_button = (isset($prev_id) && $prev_id>0)?'<a href="#" data-id="'.$prev_id.'" class="get_pic"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-circle-arrow-left rujz"></span></a>':'';
    $next_button = (isset($next_id) && $next_id>0)?'<a href="#" data-id="'.$next_id.'" class="get_pic"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-circle-arrow-right rujz"></span></a>':'';

    //output html

    echo '<div class="prod_img" style="background-image: url(pictures/';
    echo $result->slika1;
    echo '); background-size: contain; background-repeat: no-repeat; background-position: center center;">';
    echo '<h3>';
    echo $prev_button; 
    echo $result->artikel;
    echo $next_button;
    echo '</h3>';
    echo '</div>';

}
```

HTML (info.php):

```
<?php

$username = "root"; //mysql username
$password = ""; //mysql password
$hostname = "localhost"; //hostname
$databasename = '2199'; //databasename

//get pic id from ajax request
if(isset($_POST["info"]) && is_numeric($_POST["info"]))
{
    $current_info = filter_var($_POST["info"], FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
}else{
    $current_info=1;
}

//Connect to Database
$mysqli = new mysqli($hostname, $username, $password, $databasename);

if ($mysqli->connect_error){   
    die('Error : ('. $mysqli->connect_errno .') '. $mysqli->connect_error);
}

//get next picture id
$result2 = $mysqli->query("SELECT id FROM gola WHERE id > $current_info ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 1")->fetch_object();
if($result2){
    $next_id = $result2->id;
}

//get previous picture id
$result2 = $mysqli->query("SELECT id FROM gola WHERE id < $current_info ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1")->fetch_object();
if($result2){
    $prev_id = $result2->id;
}

//get details of current from database
$result2 = $mysqli->query("SELECT artikel, slika1, slika2, slika3, dim1, dim2, dim3, obdelava, dodatno FROM gola WHERE id = $current_info LIMIT 1")->fetch_object();

if($result2){

    //construct next/previous button
    $prev_button = (isset($prev_id) && $prev_id>0)?'<a href="#" data-id="'.$prev_id.'" class="get_info"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-circle-arrow-left rujz-wht"></span></a>':'';
    $next_button = (isset($next_id) && $next_id>0)?'<a href="#" data-id="'.$next_id.'" class="get_info"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-circle-arrow-right rujz-wht"></span></a>':'';

    //output html

    echo '<div class="info">';
    echo '<h3 style="color: #fff !important;">';
    echo $prev_button; 
    echo $result2->artikel;
    echo $next_button;
    echo '</h3>';
    echo '<br />';
    echo '<p>';
    echo $result2->slika1;
    echo '<br />';
    echo $result2->slika2;
    echo '<br />';
    echo $result2->slika3;
    echo '<br />';
    echo $result2->dim1;
    echo '<br />';
    echo $result2->dim2;
    echo '<br />';
    echo $result2->dim3;
    echo '<br />';
    echo $result2->obdelava;
    echo '<br />';
    echo $result2->dodatno;
    echo '</p>';
    echo '</div>';

}
```

CSS (shall you need it):

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #fff;
    font-size: 62.5%;
}
.special, .special .jumbotron {
    height: 100%;
    background-color: white;
    border: 0px solid red;
    margin-bottom: 0px !important;
}
.special2, .special2 .jumbotron {
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #62a70f;
    border: 0.5rem solid #fff;
    border-radius: 3rem;
    margin-bottom: 0px !important;
    padding: 1rem;
}
.logo {
    border: 1px solid red;
    width: 10%;
    min-height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
}
#picture {
    border: 0px red solid;
    height: 100%;
    background: #fff;
}
.prod_img {
    height: 100%;
}
h3 {
    font-family: 'Syncopate', sans-serif;
    font-size: 24px;
    font-size: 2.4rem;
    color: #62a70f;
}
.boxy {
    border: 0.5rem solid white;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 2.5%;
    right: 5%;
    width: 25%;
    padding: 1rem;
    /*  height: 30rem;*/
    background-color: rgba(64,64,64,1);
    border-radius: 3rem;/*  background-image: url(logo.png);
    background-size: contain;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;*/
}

@media (min-width:768px) {
.boxy {
    border: 0.5rem solid white;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 5%;
    right: 45%;
    width: 10%;
    /*  height: 30rem;*/
    background-color: rgba(64,64,64,1);
    border-radius: 3rem;/*  background-image: url(logo.png);
    background-size: contain;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;*/
}
.navbar {
    min-height: 10% !important;
    max-height: 10% !important;
    height: 10%;
    background-image: url(logo.png);
    background-size: contain;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    border: 0px solid green;
    background-color: #0e0e0e;
    animation-name: example;
    animation-duration: 1s;
    animation-timing-function: ease;
}
.navbar-header {
    border: 0px solid green;
    min-height: 100%;
}
.logo {
    visibility: collapse;
}
.special, .special .jumbotron {
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
    margin-bottom: 0px !important;
}
.special2, .special2 .jumbotron {
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
    margin-bottom: 0px !important;
}
h3 {
    font-size: 48px;
    font-size: 4.8rem;
}
.rujz {
    font-size: 36px;
    font-size: 3.6rem;
    color: #62a70f;
    margin: 0.5em;
}

.rujz-wht {
    font-size: 36px;
    font-size: 3.6rem;
    color: #fff;
    margin: 0.5em;
}

}
 @keyframes example {
 0% {
bottom:-10%;
}
 100% {
bottom:0%;
}
}
```

Now, my question is the following:

The image and product name display correctly inside `<div id="picture" align="center"> </div>`

What I want to accomplish is **get other data from the database and display it in the other half of the screen**. Since it all happens inside art.php, it's not as easy as typing `echo $results->columnName`, so I'd need a bit of help.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: not very clear why you can't output multiple image in same page.

Comment: You can get the other data by adding a new query like this: `$res = $mysqli->query("YOUR QUERY")->fetch_object();` and obtain it in the view via `$res->field`. Or you can just get the other data in 1 query by using [JOIN](http://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-sql-joins-mysql-database/)

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST` or `$_GET` data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: I can't get what's your expected output.

Comment: Please, check the updated code/description and live demo. It should clarify things and hopefully get me some much needed help :)

Comment: Do you get any output if you open art.php directly in the browser? If so, can you add an `alert(data);` above the `$("#picture").html( $(data).find("#loaded_picture") );` to verify that the data is correct?

Answer (score 2):

You could create an other file like art.php to display the data you need and add an other post to that file to your onclick-event.

This is how I would edited the javascript from index.php:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     $.post( "art.php", { pic: "1"}, function( data ) {
           $("#picture").html( data );
     });
     $.post( "text.php", { id: "1"}, function( data ) {
           $("#text").html( data );
     });

     $("#picture").on("click",".get_pic", function(e){
           var picture_id = $(this).attr('data-id');
           $("#picture").html("<div style=\"margin:50px auto;width:50px;\"><img src=\"loader.gif\" /></div>");
           $.post( "art.php", { pic: picture_id}, function( data ) {
                 $("#picture").html( data );
           });
           $.post( "text.php", { id: picture_id}, function( data ) {
                 $("#text").html( data );
           });
           return false;
     });
});
```

I can't really say much about text.php, since I don't know what information you want to display (or how you want to display it).

**Edit:** If you want only one post and only one external file you could use jQuerys `.find`-Function to extract portions from the ajax-data.

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     $.post( "art.php", { pic: "1"}, function( data ) {
           $("#picture").html( $(data).find("#loaded_picture") );
           $("#text").html( $(data).find("#loaded_text") );
     });

     $("#picture").on("click",".get_pic", function(e){
           var picture_id = $(this).attr('data-id');
           $("#picture").html("<div style=\"margin:50px auto;width:50px;\"><img src=\"loader.gif\" /></div>");
           $.post( "art.php", { pic: picture_id}, function( data ) {
                 $("#picture").html( $(data).find("#loaded_picture") );
                 $("#text").html( $(data).find("#loaded_text") );
           });
           return false;
     });
});
```

And in the art.php:

```
//get pic id from ajax request
if(isset($_POST["pic"]) && is_numeric($_POST["pic"])) {
    $current_picture = filter_var($_POST["pic"], FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
} else {
    $current_picture=1;
}

/* Put connect to database and other preparations here */
echo "<div>";
echo "<div id='loaded_picture'>";
// Put everything that goes into the picture div here
echo "</div>"

echo "<div id='loaded_text'>";
// And everything that goes into the text div here
echo "</div>";
echo "</div>";
```

Comment: Please, check the updated post/code, since I've used your suggestion, I guess you'll be able to help me out some more :) Thank you!

Comment: @SebastianPelan I assumed, that the picture and the information belong together and should update together, so I put the change for the information into the same onclick-event as used for the picture. I see that you split them - should they be navigated separatly?

Comment: @SebastianPelan As for why you can't navigate the descriptions: The problem lies in the `$.post( "info.php", { pic: info_id}, function( data ) {/*stuff*/});` and the `$_POST["info"]` - the `{ pic: info_id }` gets send to the server, who puts it down as `$_POST["pic"] = info_id`, but you're asking for `$_POST["info"]`, which it hasn't got.

Comment: Hey, thanks! I'm trying again with your original code with both posts combined and it still doesn't work. It does get the data of the first product and display it correctly in the right section, but I can only navigate back and forth on the left section, the right one is stuck on the first photo... I'm sure it's a single line to fix somewhere... and my lack of knowledge doesn't help much... Any ideas?

Comment: @SebastianPelan What `$_POST`-Variable are you checking for in your info.php? If you are using my example you would need to check for `$_POST["id"]`, with the javasrcipt you provided you would need to check for `$_POST["pic"]`.

Comment: @SebastianPelan I edited my answer and added a one-file-solution.

Comment: Thanks again! I'm sure we're getting there, but we're still not there. Tried fiddling with it too, but couldn't get anything out of it no matter how I modified it (of course, I first tried your code with no changes at all). The divs are not appearing anywhere in the final output... I'm starting to think I should just code everything as static (sub)pages and leave dynamic pages and databases to the pros ;)

Comment: Sorry, looks like I made a mistake, there needs to be an additional wrapper around the divs in the art.php (updated answer)

Comment: Still nothing :( Nevermind, I'm obviously out of luck with this project, so I better use the little time I have left to hack it all together in plain html before I get fired :D

Answer (score 0):

By looking at your index.php i think you are having trouble updating your

```
$result->artikel
```

in the table section when you call another image in. If this is the case then you can do this wrap your `$result->artikel` in art.php file with a div like `<div class="artikel">$result->artikel</div>` and echo it. Now you can do this to update your table section with the new data.

```
$("#picture").on("click",".get_pic", function(e){
    var picture_id = $(this).attr('data-id');
    $("#picture").html("<div style=\"margin:50px auto;width:50px;\"><img src=\"loader.gif\" /></div>");
    $.post( "art.php", { pic: picture_id}, function( data ) {
        $("#picture").html( data );

        //you should give class name to p that's easy after to work
        $("table thead th:nth-child(2) p").html($(".artikel").html());

    });
    return false;
});
```

This will update your table section also